# the meaning of the phrase: "she sucks badly at it"

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

What does the phrase: "**she sucks badly at it**" mean?

My hypotheses are:

1. She doesn't like it
2. She is bad at doing it

It is a passage from the Emily Giffin's book "Where We Belong".

If you need more context here it is:

> "My dad typically picks up the story from there, telling me how he cut himself shaving, his hands shaking so much that he almost let my mother drive to the hospital, *something he never does because **she sucks so badly at it**.* Then he skips ahead to the papers they hurriedly signed, and the moment the lady from the agency returned with a baby—me—swaddled in a pink fleece blanket."

Comment: Have you tried looking up [**sucks**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suck) in a dictionary?

Comment: @stevees of course I have. But none of the meanings from the dictionary seems to fit here or I simply doesn't understand something

Comment: Intransitive verb, definition 4 (in the above link) _"slang, sometimes vulgar:  to be objectionable or inadequate"_. I.e. she is very bad at driving.

Comment: can it mean "she doesn't like it"?

Comment: No - it can't mean _"she doesn't like it."._ That would be _"She thinks it sucks."_

Comment: @RuslanMukhanov it's basically a synonym for _is bad_. So "she sucks" = "she is bad" and "it sucks" = "it is bad". The exact meaning of _what_ or _how_ something or someone is bad must be inferred from context.

Comment: @adam put it as the answer and i'll mark it answered

Comment: @Ruslan Mukhanov: You should probably forget you ever came across this slang usage of ***to suck***. Because it's pretty downmarket slang, some people will think badly of you for using it *whether you get the syntax right or not*, but (also because it's slangy, and relatively new) the precise definition of "syntactically valid usage" won't be unanimously agreed by all native speakers anyway. Personally, I wouldn't accept *He sucks **badly** at golf*, for example, but quite possibly it's okay to others.

Comment: It's not new. I've been using it for 30 years. It does still offend some, mostly older and prudish people.

Comment: @Fumblefingers - I think this usage of _sucks_ may be more common in America - I hear it all the time from people of all ages.  For instance at work, I wouldn't expect to hear it used in a presentation for people outside my company, but I wouldn't be surprised to hear it at an internal presentation.

Comment: @Rob K: In terms of neologistic language use, I'd say 30 years is relatively recent. In fact, [the slang sense of "be contemptible"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=suck&allowed_in_frame=0) was first attested somewhat earlier (1971), but as pointed out there by etymonline, it was *very* closely associated with fellatio at that time (and still is today, to some). So there's plenty of scope for people to object to the usage *generically*, on the grounds of "good taste" (sorry! :) as well as in specific syntactic contexts (*I suck **quite a lot** at golf,* anybody?).

Comment: @RuslanM: A good way to avoid being asked "Did you look this up in the dictionary?" is to tell us that you've looked it up in the dictionary. If you don't tell us, some will wonder if you are confused, or just lazy. If you do tell us, it will be a lot easier for us to understand why you are confused. For more info, check out the "Show your research" part of our [_Details, Please_](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) meta question. (That all said, I'm glad you provided the passage from the book; that helps, too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP's option 2 is correct.  [idiomeaning.com](http://www.idiomeanings.com/suck-at/) defines it as:

> to be terrible at something

In this instance, their definition *is* correct.